# How can i set profile pic against firebase user authentication with email?

Tags: swift3, firebase-realtime-database

i am developing an employee management app thats why i need to save profile picture against  employee id or email .In firebase database what is the process and how can i design database through source code.In swift 3,xcode 8.3.2,ios 10.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the profile Image on the firebase storage,
after that imageURL will be retrieved. After the imageURL is retrieved you need to save it on the firebase database as a child of the userId.
Refer the code below

```
func handleRegister() {
    guard let email = self.emailTextField.text, let password = self.passwordTextField.text, let name = self.nameTextField.text  else {
        print("Form is not valid")
        return
    }
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user: User?, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        guard let uid = user?.uid else {
            return
        }
        //success
        let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("\(imageName).png")
        if let uploadData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.profileImageView.image!, 0.1) {
            storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion:
                { (metadata, error) in
                    if  error != nil {
                        print(error!)
                        return
                    }
                    print(metadata!)
                    if let progileImageURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {
                        let values = ["name": name, "email": email, "profileImageUrl": progileImageURL]
                        self.registerUserIntoDatabaseWithUID(uid: uid, values: values as [String : AnyObject])
                    }
            })
        }
    }
}


func registerUserIntoDatabaseWithUID(uid: String, values: [String: AnyObject]) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let userRef = ref.child("users").child(uid)
    userRef.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
        if err != nil {
            print(err!)
            return
        }
        print("Saved user successfully into Firebase db")
        self.messagesController1?.checkIfUseLoggedin()
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?
    if let editedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage {
        selectedImageFromPicker = editedImage
        print(editedImage)
    }
    else if let orignalImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
        selectedImageFromPicker = orignalImage
        print(orignalImage)
    }
    if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker {
        self.profileImageView.image = selectedImage
    }
   self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    print("picker cancled")
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```